# how to get shuffled batch from tfrecords with limited memory but large data set?

Tags: tensorflow, shuffle

Using the tensorflow function **tf.train.shuffle_batch** we get shuffled batch by reading tfrecord into memory as a queue and shuffling within the queue (Umm, if i get the right understanding). Now I have a highly ordered tfrecords (pics of the same label are written together) and a really large dataset (around 2,550,000 pics). I want to feed my Vgg-net with batch of random labels, but its impossible and ugly to read all pictures into memory and get shuffled. Is there any solution to this?

I thought about maybe first doing shuffling then writing them into TFrecord, but I can't figure out an effective way doing this...

my data are saved in this way:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FieUj.png)

Here is my code getting TFRecords:

```
dst = "/Users/cory/Desktop/3_key_frame"

classes=[]
for myclass in os.listdir(dst):
    if myclass.find('.DS_Store')==-1:
        classes.append(myclass)


writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter("train.tfrecords")
for index, name in enumerate(classes):
    class_path = dst +'/' + name
    #print(class_path)
    for img_seq in os.listdir(class_path):
        if img_seq.find('DS_Store')==-1:
            seq_pos = class_path +'/' + img_seq
            if os.path.isdir(seq_pos):
                for img_name in os.listdir(seq_pos):
                    img_path = seq_pos +'/' + img_name
                    img = Image.open(img_path)
                    img = img.resize((64,64))
                    img_raw = img.tobytes()
                    #print (img,index)
                    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                        "label":tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[index])),
                        'img_raw':tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[img_raw]))
                        }))
                    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming you have the known list of filenames and/or structure of your labelled dataset.
It may be worthwhile iterating through them on a class-by-class basis taking N amount each time. In essence interleaving the datasets so that you don't have sequential issues.
If I am understanding this correctly, your primary concern is when sampling your dataset from the TFRecord that a sub-set of your data may contain entirely 1 class, rather than a good representation?

If you structure it as:

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ... etc
```

this may make the **shuffle_batch** more likely to create a nicer sample for training.

This is the solution I am following, as there appears to be no additional params for shuffling where you can specify to keep a uniform distribution of class labels amongst the set.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your data is stored like this:

```
/path/to/images/LABEL_1/image001.jpg
/path/to/images/LABEL_1/image002.jpg
...
/path/to/images/LABEL_10/image001.jpg
```

Get all the filenames in a flat list and shuffle them:

```
import glob
import random
filenames = glob.glob('/path/to/images/**/*.jpg)
random.shuffle(filenames)
```

Create a dictionary to go from label name to numerical label:

```
class_to_index = {'LABEL_1':0, 'LABEL_2': 1} # more classes I assume...
```

Now you can loop over all images and retrieve the label

```
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter("train.tfrecords")
for f in filenames:
    img = Image.open(f)
    img = img.resize((64,64))
    img_raw = img.tobytes()
    label = f.split('/')[-2]
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                    "label":tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value= class_to_index[label])),
                    'img_raw':tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[img_raw]))
                    }))
                writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
```

Hope this helps :)